# Elasticsearch: Return empty value from script field

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I'm using Elasticsearch, and I have a script field written in Groovy. It needs to replace the value of `myField` for some values, but I want to let most of the values pass through unchanged. The script below works except for documents that don't have the field at all. How can I make the script field value empty?

```
if (some criteria) {
    return ...; // modified value
}
//  This returns 0 if myField doesn't exist
return doc['myField'].value
```

I can check the empty condition, but I haven't found a way to return an empty value:

```
if (doc['myField'].empty)
    return ???
```

Comment: By "empty value", do you mean an empty string?

Comment: @Val no, I mean more like null.  If I return null, I get an exception though.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly ok to return `null`. I think the problem is more in the sequencing of your different test conditions. I've tried to reproduce your issue and I'm able to return `null` with the following script:

```
  "script_fields": {
    "my_script_field": {
      "script": "if (doc.myField.empty) { return null } else if (some criteria) { return modifiedValue } else { return doc.myField.value }"
    }
  }
```

First check for fields with empty values and return `null`. 
Then, you're guaranteed to have non-empty and existing fields. So you can check for your criteria and return whatever modified field you want.
Finally, you can return the unmodified values for non-empty fields which do not meet your specified criteria.

The script looks like this:

```
if (doc.myField.empty) { 
   return null 
} else if (some criteria) { 
   return modifiedValue 
} else { 
   return doc.myField.value 
}
```